# Is it feasible to pass HANDLE(S) to another function?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw32

When compiling like this:

```
void DisplayPos (void)
{
    SetWindowPos (ConsoleWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 600, 600, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}

int main (void)
{
    HWND ConsoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
    DisplayPos ();
}
```

GCC will report:

```
Line 3 | error: 'ConsoleWindow' undeclared (first use in this function) // expected
```

But is it feasible to pass HANDLE to another function without declaring a new one? Thanks.

Comment: Passing handles is just fine -- but you actually have to *pass* them.  Functions can't see each other's local variables.

Comment: @cHao So, how to pass HANDLE(s) ?

Comment: See that `(void)`?  That's where parameters go, and `void` means you aren't accepting any.  Try declaring it as `void DisplayPos(HWND ConsoleWindow)` instead.  Then you can pass the handle in the parentheses whenever you call `DisplayPos`, like `DisplayPos(ConsoleWindow);`.

Comment: @cHao Oh, Thx. I see. `HWND` is also a type like `int`, `char` etc. Right?

Comment: Yep.  It's actually an alias for an existing built-in type, but you don't need to care about that.  Just treat it like you would any other value type, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I would suggest that before you try to learn Windows programming, you first learn C programming. Trying to learn both at the same time is going to be very difficult.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Thanks for the advice. I'm mainly learning C now, but some Windows APIs are needed for changing the Console Windows' Properties. :-)

Comment: Maybe start with `Hello World`.

Comment: Most developers never need to change console window properties from a program, because that is suppose to be an end user decision. I don't think I've ever done it in any real program (i.e. other than just demonstration), and I've been doing this for decades.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Well, I am not really a programmer, and I learn programming just in my interest.(I am a 7th grader) Recently, I am working on game programming with WinAPI (ie. GDI32) and C99 for console windows, so I need to use it to control the console windows' attributes (ie. Size, Titlebar, Close button etc.)  :-)

Comment: I would recommend that you focus on your game first. You can deal with the title bar later. Writing the game will give you the experience you need to do the other stuff.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I think it might be a little abstract to what I am saying about. Maybe you can [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hh5CMqE2ZmamFrdFVRSkttcjQ/edit?usp=sharing) to download the very rough miniature of the game if you are interested in.

Comment: Great. Go write that game. Don't worry about the Close button right now.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I'll do my best! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate @cHao 's help. :-)

I answered my own question.

```
void DisplayPos (HWND ConsoleWindow)
{
    SetWindowPos (ConsoleWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 600, 600, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}

int main (void)
{
    HWND ConsoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
    DisplayPos (ConsoleWindow);
}
```